# NSTrackingArea yields different results when initialized with initWithRect:[self bounds] and [self frame]

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

--------- Question 1 ----------
Maybe I don't understand the frame object completely (or maybe it wasn't created correctly in my context), but as I was trying to implement a mouse event I encountered the situation where the call:

```
trackingArea=[ [NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:[self frame] options:(NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingMouseMoved | NSTrackingActiveInKeyWindow) owner:self userInfo:nil ];
```

Resulted in incorrect tracking area (only top right corner worked) - looking into the problem I found that 'frame' started somewhere in top right corner. This call was made in an overloaded initWithFrame defined as:

```
glView = [ [ Lesson17View alloc ] initWithFrame:[ glWindow frame ]
colorBits:16 depthBits:16 fullscreen:FALSE ];
```

where glView is subclassed from NSOpenGLView. The above call is made in awakeFromNib, and glWindow is defined as:

IBOutlet NSWindow *glWindow;

When I replace bounds with frame, my application works - what is going on with the frame variable?

--------- Question 2 ----------

My second question involves how to handle the mouse events and correctly have my openGL view redraw - say I have:

```
- (void) mouseMoved:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
NSPoint location=[self convertPoint:[theEvent locationInWindow] fromView:nil];
// send NSPoint to a printGL function I have that uses texture maps to display text?
}
```

I'm guessing I shouldn't be sending this to a function that renders something in my openGL view (because this doesn't do anything -guessing because whenever I use drawRect whatever I drew during the mouse event is cleared). Currently all my drawing is perfomed in drawRect (contains a bunch of openGL calls) - what would be the appropriate call to make at this point?

Or should I set a flag (along with setting an instance variable NSPoint) to true that will allow printGL to be called only on mouseMoved events (I know - I'll use the mouseEntered/Exited functions but for now I'm trying to get a handle on this).

Comment: You should probably split this into two different questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A view's **frame** is where the view is located *in its superview*. This means most importantly that unless the view's origin is right on top of its superview's origin (i.e. at `{0, 0}`), the frame rectangle will be offset by that amount.

A view's **bounds** are the coordinates *inside the view*. Unless you've applied some transform to the view's coordinate system, the bounds origin will always be at `{0, 0}`.

So, why does this make a difference in your case? As [noted in the docs for NSTrackingArea](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTrackingArea_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTrackingArea/initWithRect%3aoptions%3aowner%3auserInfo%3a), the rect is interpreted as coordinates *in the coordinate system of the tracking area's owner*. The owner's bounds are in its coordinate system, while the frame is in coordinate system of the owner's superview. So you're giving the tracking area a rect from the wrong coordinate system.

I highly recommend reading the [View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/Coordinates/Coordinates.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002978-CH10-SW1). It explains all of this and more. There are a lot of subtle details to the Cocoa view system that you'll want to know when you're writing UI code.

(And for your second question: To tell a view to redraw, send it `[view setNeedsDisplay:YES]`.)

Comment: Thanks for the view programming guide - I'm still confused as to why my glView's frame has an origin that is in the top right of its super view (it was initialized with the super view's frame - so I don't understand why these two values are not identical)


also - I shouldn't have any opengl commands (or calls to opengl for that matter) in my mouseMoved method right? I should set values that will be used in the when drawRect is called (i.e. a flag to draw something based on the mouse's position, which will be queried).

Comment: Ok so I guess I answered my own question a little - the reason glView had the frame offset was because the superview was offset (This was the main NSWindow instance)...